# only shows the correct session of email address but wrong username

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

One thing I recognized is that the clause I set in the PDO Prepared is only two clauses like this:

```
 WHERE myemail = :myemail AND mypassword = :mypassword
```

So, what I want to try now is that I want to set three clause in the PDO Prepared, like this:

```
 WHERE myemail = :myemail, mypassword = :mypassword, AND username = :username
```

But I am not sure if I do that correctly. I am just learnig php (self-taught).

---

I ask this question is because the index page only shows the correct session of email address but wrong username.

When I log in from username of "someone" with email of "someone@mail.com", the index page show the correct username and email address with the session.

However, when I log in from username of "somebody" with email of "somebody@mail.com", the index page show the correct email (somebody@ymail.com) but with the wrong username (someone) not (somebody).

Here is my code:

```
// Define $myusername and $mypassword
   $myemail=$_POST['myemail']; 
   $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 


// We Will prepare SQL Query
   $STM = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM newuser WHERE myemail = :myemail AND mypassword = :mypassword");


// bind paramenters, Named paramenters alaways start with colon(:)
   $STM->bindParam(':myemail', $myemail);
   $STM->bindParam(':mypassword', $mypassword);

// For Executing prepared statement we will use below function
   $STM->execute();

// Count no. of records 
   $count = $STM->rowCount();

//just fetch. only gets one row. So no foreach loop needed :)
  $row  = $STM -> fetch();



// User Redirect Conditions will go here
    if ( $count == 1 )  {
       $_SESSION['login_id'] = $row['id'];
       $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username']; // added
       $_SESSION['myemail'] = $row['myemail']; // added

    if ( $_SESSION['login_id'] != '' || $_SESSION['login_id'] > 0 ) { // edited
        header("location: index.php");  
    } else { 
        header("location: login3.html");  
    }
}
```

---

```
 <?php
 include('UserSessionAdmin.php');
 $username = $_SESSION['username'];
 $myemail = $_SESSION['myemail'];
 ?>
 <body>
 <?php echo $username; ?>
 <?php echo $myemail; ?>
 </body>
```

---

UserSessionAdmin.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if ( $_SESSION['login_id'] == 0 || $_SESSION['login_id'] == '' ) {
    header('location: login.html');
    exit();
}

require_once('configPDO.php');
?>
```

**Update**:

When I added `echo var_dump($row);` before the line `$count==1`, the page shows up with this result:

`array(6) { ["username"]=> string(8) "Somebody" [0]=> string(8) "Somebody" ["myemail"]=> string(17) "somebody@mail.com" [1]=> string(17) "somebody@mail.com" ["mypassword"]=> string(8) "thebest2" [2]=> string(8) "thebest2" }`

Comment: You're not actually EXECUTING your query. You're preparing it, but then you never do `$STM->execute();`

Comment: Presuming you have removed some parts of your code for this question (as is it wont run at all) the conditional `if ( $count == 1 )` suggests there is only one result in the database, so restricting the query wont help - your data must be incorrect, or some unseen code is overwriting `$_SESSION['username']`

Comment: @Steve I completed the code, can you please check it for me what is wrong there?

Comment: @AlKush Your code looks fine, so i expect the data is wrong. Whats actually in your database? If it seems fine, please add `echo var_dump($row);` before `if( $count...` line, (and comment out the redirects) and update your question with the result

Comment: @Steve I am sorry for the late reply. Btw, I just give it a try and updated the question with the result. Please check it. I don't have any idea what it means.

Comment: @AlKush OK, well that shows the data is fine as well - there is nothing in your code to explain your problem im afraid.

Comment: But there is something weird there, why it printed something two times?

Comment: the wrong email you see, is it from the previous login ? or is just wrong value

Comment: @meda, It must not from the previous login, I am very sure.

Comment: Btw, I dont see there what you mean about "the wrong email"?

Comment: @AlKush try my suggestion below

Comment: @AlKush `why it printed something two times?` Thats the expected behaviour of `fetch();` - it returns an array index both by column name and numerically. if you just what an asociative array: `->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php This has nothing to do with your problem

Comment: @Steve, thanks for the reference, I will study it. Btw, Meda just solved the problem. :)

Comment: @AlKush great, although i think his solution is meant to be just a step in debugging - it proves the problem is with your session storage, but it doesnt solve the issue. I expect he will follow up with more help though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well from what you are saying this is very strange, here is how I would debug it:

```
 header("location: index.php?username=".$row['username]."&myemail=".$row['myemail']);
```

then

```
 <?php
 include('UserSessionAdmin.php');
 //$username = $_SESSION['username'];
 //$myemail = $_SESSION['myemail'];
 $username = $_GET['username'];
 $myemail = $_GET['myemail'];
 ?>
 <body>
 <?php echo $username; ?>
 <?php echo $myemail; ?>
 </body>
```

This isn't a direct answer, this will help you narrow down the issue.

If this works it is clear that the SESSION is responsible for this.

---

**EDIT:**

`$_GET` was used just for the sake of debugging, of course it is not meant for that.

Now we know its the session, you always need to make sure it is started.

When you set it:

```
if ( $count == 1 )  {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login_id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['myemail'] = $row['myemail'];
    ...
}
```

When you get it:

```
include('UserSessionAdmin.php');
session_start();//again!
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$myemail = $_SESSION['myemail'];
```

Comment: Thank you for coming here. :)

Comment: when I copied-paste the link of a user login, for exampple `index.php?username=someone&myemail=someone@yahoo.com` it can enter the index page without I have to login first. Please help me how to fix this, so that the index page can't be accessed by copying the link of user login. thanks.

Comment: You are still using query strings? I thought you would switch back to session, thats the way to persist data!

Comment: But please help me how to do that. I don't have any idea.

Comment: When I do that, the problem backs to the first issue, which is it fetches the wrong username. Can you please find out the main problem please, it really makes me confuse since this two weeks.

Comment: I can fix it if only what I post there is the username, not the email adresss. But as you know, usernames might be same to each other, but not the email. So, what I need is to post the email, not the username. But the problem is that. Why does it always echo the wrong username, but the correct email address.

Comment: I hope you can explain it to me here, just to help me out with my basic php studying. Sincerely.

Comment: The code you show should store the row value into the session do  `echo $row['username'];` to confirm

Comment: Meda, I need to solve it here, that's now I start the bounty for this question. I have edited the echo like this `<?php echo $row['username'];?>` but it doesn't echo anything now. :(

Comment: Well It still ask me to wait to three hours again. Can't wait to give the bounty.

Comment: no worries, if you post a question and dont get a solution just hit me up okay

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE myemail = :myemail, mypassword = :mypassword, AND username = :username
```

Just throw another `AND` in there:

```
WHERE myemail = :myemail AND mypassword = :mypassword AND username = :username
```

> When I log in from username of "someone" with email of "someone@mail.com", the index page show the correct username and email address with the session.

You should be using the data from the database as the source of truth, not what the user entered in a form.  Do your query and rely on data in your result set only.

Comment: Correct sytnax, but wont address the underlying problem

Comment: @Brad, thanks for the comprehension. Btw, I completed the codes in my question, can you please check it for me to find out something wrong there?

Answer (score 1):

You use AND between each of the clauses in a WHERE query, so like this:

```
WHERE myemail = :myemail AND mypassword = :mypassword AND username = :username
```

The , is used for selecting fields. (And some other things, but not for stringing together a WHERE clause)

EDIT: the question has been severely altered since this answer was given, so it's no longer relevant.